# Comparing xml Attribute with String finds no match

Tags: xml, vb.net, string

How can I compare these two correctly

```
If xanswer.@state = "ERROR" And xanswer.@errormsg = **"Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.& #xD;&#xA;Parametername: XMLStruct (Attributes country)"** Then


< response state="ERROR" errormsg="Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.&#xD;&#xA;Parametername: XMLStruct (Attributes country)" xmlns=""></response >
```

I believe he doesnt jump into the if path because of the `& #xD;&#xA` 
in the xml Attribute. it means in the xml attribute something different then in the string. 
Can someone approve this?
I tried to replace the  `& #xD;&#xA`  in the string with `& vbCrlf &`but it didn't work

```
If xanswer.@state = "ERROR" And xanswer.@errormsg = "Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein." And xanswer.errormsg.@Parametername = " XMLStruct (Attributes country)" Then
```

and

```
If xanswer.@state = "ERROR" And xanswer.@errormsg = "Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein." And xanswer.@errormsg = "Parametername:  XMLStruct (Attributes country)" Then
```

doesnt work.

As XML attributes are all Strings I used the .contains Method for the selection. thx to the first answer.

Comment: Can you check instead for the erromsg containing the string "Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein", and also "Parametername: XMLStruct (Attributes country)".  This might be useful if you have several NULL errors but have to act differently depending on the parameter name

Comment: checked as good as I can. how would you do it?

Comment: Thx for the editing It looks like I need to learn to format my text better in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using string functions `StartWith()` and `EndWith()` to match that XML element and skip checking `& #xD;&#xA;` part :

```
If xanswer.@state = "ERROR" And _
   xanswer.@errormsg.StartsWith("Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.") And _
   xanswer.@errormsg.EndsWith(" XMLStruct (Attributes country)") Then
```